# Что такое «мундиаль»?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, неологизмы

В последнее время я заметил, что часто о чемпионате мира говорят, используя слово «мундиаль». Что оно значит и как произошло?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mundial** — в переводе с испанского мировой, всемирный. Вошло в некоторые языки мира в качестве синонима к "Чемпионат мира по футболу". См., например, [en-викисловарь](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mundial), где в четырёх из пяти приведенных языков упомянуто это значение.

Распространялось через журналистов, я полагаю.